# Event Log: Faulting application name: Fabric.exe, version: 1.0.960.0

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I'm working on a SP2013. It was setup by someone else.

I fixed most issues. But then I found there is this entry in event log. It happens frequently. Anyone knows anything about this error?

> Faulting application name: Fabric.exe, version: 1.0.960.0, time stamp:
>   0x50415e97 Faulting module name: Fabric.exe, version: 1.0.960.0, time
>   stamp: 0x50415e97 Exception code: 0xc0000602 Fault offset:
>   0x00000000001d01e8 Faulting process id: 0x1020 Faulting application
>   start time: 0x01cf09a6e3fbfda9 Faulting application path: C:\Program
>   Files\Windows Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code.1.0\Fabric.exe Faulting
>   module path: C:\Program Files\Windows
>   Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code.1.0\Fabric.exe Report Id:
>   21d1117d-759a-11e3-b996-00155d01b500

(this is all it has in event log, no more details).

Comment: could you please check and make sure Distributed cache cluster is up and running, if running then try to recyle it.
check below article and try to repair it.http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219613.aspx

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. eventually, we decided to reinstall it and attach the content database. fixed some url link issues, so far so good.